# Is there any way to configure launcherArgs in plugin.xml file instead of product.xml file in eclipse rcp?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have to configure `launcherArgs` in plugin.xml file under `<product>` tag, is there any solution?

```
  <launcherArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Xms125m -Xmx900m -Xss4m 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=90 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
      </vmArgs>     
   </launcherArgs>
```

Comment: If you want to change the `*.ini` file of your RCP application (which is global for all plug-ins) when the plug-in is installed, you can do this via a `p2.inf` file. What arguments and why do you want to configure?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is nothing to do with any plugin.xml

The `launcherArgs` values end up in the `-vmargs` section of the `rcp.ini` file generated for your RCP (where `rcp` is the name of your RCP executable).

Note that these values are only used for launching the RCP, they have nothing to do with any launches you might do from within the RCP.